# View 'Select all' label in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got ssrs 2012 and I have to create report with parameters (multivalue).
My question is:
Is it possible to set label to "Checked all", when someone checked all possible values? Now I've got all labels listed...

Thanks,
Mat

Comment: Can you edit the question and add what you've tried and where you've looked so far, and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display all the selected values for a parameter you'll usually write an expression like:

```
=Join(Parameters!MyParam.Label, ",")
```

If you want to display "Checked all" instead of all the different parameters listed first you need to know how many parameters you're displaying on the multi-value field. If the list of values is coming from a query to the database you can use the following expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!MyParam.Label.Length = Count(Fields!Label.Value, "DataSet1"), 
"Checked all", Join(Parameters!MyParam.Label, ","))
```